# A finite group with a threshold functionality

Tags: finite-field, group-theory

I am trying to find a generator of a finite group that its powers devides the group into two parts. For example look at the last row of this table that shows the powers of 10 in the group Z_19.
[image]

You can devide the group to two part. the elements before "10^7 mod 19" that all of them are less than "13" and the elements containing and after "10^7 mod 19" that with probablity 1/2 are more than "13". I am trying to find a group with modulo of a large prime(as large as be secure for cryptographic purpose) and a generator that can devide the group to two part as I explained before. It would be more desired if a group can be found that the probablity 1/2 that we talked about before be closer to 1.
I don't care if the partition be based on something different and not greater than or less than "13". Any partition that can be easily checked would be useful.

Comment: Sorry, but many things are unclear. First and foremost, is a large multiplicative group required, and if not how is the question relevant to cryptography? Is there some size requirement on the two partitions ? Can we change the test criteria $(g^x\bmod p)<13$ to something different, like "$g^x\bmod p$ is odd"? Can we change the partition criteria $x<7$ to something different, like $(x\bmod5)<2$?

Comment: yes, I need a large multiplicative group because I need the discrete log to be computationally hard. I need both the partitions to have the size o(n). test criteria can be anything that is computationally feasible. partition criteria should be in the form x<a for some a.

Comment: Remark, possibly a hint: it seems that any such method would give an advantage to guess if $x<a$ for random $x$, given $g^x\bmod p$.

Comment: Yes but anyway it is a guess. Always given  g^x mod p you can have a probability distribution on the x but doesn't matter because it is just a probability distribution.

Comment: Given $g^x\bmod p$ for $(p,g)$ as used in cryptography, and random $x$, we typically can't guess something interesting about $x$ (that is, something with probability and it's complement both non-vanishing). A rare exception is that if the order of $g$ is even, we can tell the parity of $x$. And that can't happen when the order of $g$ is a large prime, which is customary.